# How to Free/Release a File in Python?

Tags: python, file, operating-system

I get "file being used by another process" errors during execution when using os.stat.

I'm trying to sort a directory with help of os.stat and then using those files in an external process.

```
all_files = []
for file in os.listdir(some_directory):
    stats = os.stat(join(some_directory, file))
    if stats[ST_CTIME] == stats[ST_MTIME]:
        #file has not been modified yet
        all_files.append((file, stats[ST_SIZE]))
for file in all_files:
    # Try to open the file in an external process
    # "file being used by another process"
```

It works when I comment out os.stat and use fake stats instead. So it really is os.stat that blocks file access.

How can I release the file, so it can be opened in an external process?

Comment: May be you are opening that file already in some type of text reader or something like that ?

Comment: Close the other program using the file.